# Flask: use [GET, POST] function for a single URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, flask, get

I'm new to Flask and wondering if it is possible to use the same URL to display a form in html and query to display something

Ideally, I want to have the following result to happen.

If I'm going to create a query inside 138.10.2.1/sample by doing this:

```
http://138.10.2.1:8000/sample?psi=1&lavr=1&dsc=1&ifsc=1&ics=1&eng=3&ol1=1&ol2=1&reso=1&educ=1&listen=1&time=1&probe=1&unders=1
```

It will display:

```
*something in json format*
```

in the webpage

Else, if I'll just go straight to this:

```
http://138.10.2.1:8000/sample
```

It will direct me to a .html page with a form to fill or allow a user to attach a file to use and upload to display a transformed file in json format also.

Here's my code

sample.py

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, make_response, send_from_directory, render_template
import convert as ps

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sample", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query_strings():

    #This is not working: if request.method == "POST":

        args1 = request.args["psi"]
        args2 = request.args["lavr"]
        args3 = request.args["dsc"]
        args4 = request.args["ifsc"]
        args5 = request.args["ics"]
        args6 = request.args["eng"]
        args7 = request.args["ol1"]
        args8 = request.args["ol2"]
        args9 = request.args["reso"]
        args10 = request.args["educ"]
        args11 = request.args["listen"]
        args12 = request.args["time"]
        args13 = request.args["probe"]
        args14 = request.args["unders"]

        args_list = [args1, args2, args3, args4, args5, args6, args7, args8,args9, args10, args11, args12, args13, args14]


        result = ps.execute(args_list)
        response = app.response_class(
            response=result,
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
        return response
    #This is my html form: return render_template("form.html")
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Right now, what I can have is to run the query but I am getting prompted to enter the paramaters I declared if I just entered:

```
http://138.10.2.1:8000/sample
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you want to test for GET with or without arguments.

Comment: What do you meant be testing using GET?

When I use this:
"if request.method == "GET":"

- It will allow me to use the URL to get the result based from arguements
- If I didn't enter any parameter, it do not redirect me to the form.html

Comment: I mean `http://138.10.2.1:8000/sample?psi=1&lavr=1&dsc=...` is GET with parameters and `http://138.10.2.1:8000/sample` is without parameters. You want different output for these 2 cases.

Comment: Ohh..I see..so how can I have a .html to display if I don't enter any parameters? This will allow me to attach a file inside the html form and create to POST and get the same json result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the number of arguments and return the HTML form if the length is 0 like this:

```
    # if there are no arguments provided, show HTML form
    if len(request.args) == 0:
        return render_template("form.html")
```

Also, there's no need to store each argument as a separate variable and then combine them into a list. `request.args` is already a dictionary so you can simply get a list of the argument names and values with:

```
list(request.args.keys()) # list of argument names eg. ['psi', 'lavr', 'dsc', 'ifsc'...]
list(request.args.values()) # list of argument values eg. [1, 1, 1, 1...]
```

You can check if the argument names match a desired set:

```
if set(argument_names) == {"psi","lavr","dsc","ifsc","ics","eng","ol1","ol2","reso","educ","listen","time","probe","unders"}:
        # return JSON
```

Overall, your code could look something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sample", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query_strings():
    # if there are no arguments provided, show HTML form
    if len(request.args) == 0:
        return render_template("form.html")

    argument_names = list(request.args.keys())

    # if the argument list is valid
    if set(argument_names) == {"psi","lavr","dsc","ifsc","ics","eng","ol1","ol2","reso","educ","listen","time","probe","unders"}:
        # return JSON
        response = app.response_class(
                response=json.dumps(request.args),
                status=200,
                mimetype='application/json'
        )
        return response

    return "Invalid arguments"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

This will:

- show `form.html` if you load `/sample` with no arguments
- show the arguments as JSON if you load `/sample` with valid arguments (eg. `/sample?psi=1&lavr=1&dsc=1&ifsc=1&ics=1&eng=3&ol1=1&ol2=1&reso=1&educ=1&listen=1&time=1&probe=1&unders=1`)
- show "Invalid arguments" in any other case

Comment: This is awesome! Not only you answered my question but also optimized my code. Thank you! :) I learned alot!!

Answer (score 1):

> Ohh..I see..so how can I have a .html to display if I don't enter any parameters? This will allow me to attach a file inside the html form and create to POST and get the same json result

Based on your comment to the question and sample code you've posted I assume you might be looking for something like this:

```
@app.route("/sample", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query_strings():
    args1 = request.args.get("psi")
    args2 = request.args.get("lavr")
    args3 = request.args.get("dsc")
    args4 = request.args.get("ifsc")
    args5 = request.args.get("ics")
    args6 = request.args.get("eng")
    args7 = request.args.get("ol1")
    args8 = request.args.get("ol2")
    args9 = request.args.get("reso")
    args10 = request.args.get("educ")
    args11 = request.args.get("listen")
    args12 = request.args.get("time")
    args13 = request.args.get("probe")
    args14 = request.args.get("unders")

    args_list = [
        args1, args2, args3, args4, args5, args6, args7, args8,
        args9, args10, args11, args12, args13, args14
    ]

    if not all(args_list):
        return render_template('form.html')
    else:
        result = ps.execute(args_list)
        response = app.response_class(
            response=result,
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
        return response
```

In this case, if you give no parameters in GET request it will render a template with html form.

Also rather than always check for request method I suggest you take a look at Flask's MethodView. Using that you can nicely split you logic onto request with arguments in the query string and form submitting with json:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.views.MethodView

Comment: That seems about correct also..But I wanted to use POST method to pass .html which can be accomplished on the answer that I accepted.. Thank you also!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope it will help you. By default, it uses the GET method, so it is not working. When you click on the submit button then it calls the POST method.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, make_response, send_from_directory, render_template
import convert as ps

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sample", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def query_strings():

    if request.method == "POST":

        args1 = request.args["psi"]
        args2 = request.args["lavr"]
        args3 = request.args["dsc"]
        args4 = request.args["ifsc"]
        args5 = request.args["ics"]
        args6 = request.args["eng"]
        args7 = request.args["ol1"]
        args8 = request.args["ol2"]
        args9 = request.args["reso"]
        args10 = request.args["educ"]
        args11 = request.args["listen"]
        args12 = request.args["time"]
        args13 = request.args["probe"]
        args14 = request.args["unders"]

        args_list = [args1, args2, args3, args4, args5, args6, args7, args8,args9, args10, args11, args12, args13, args14]


        result = ps.execute(args_list)
        response = app.response_class(
            response=result,
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
        )
        # return response
        return render_template("form.html", response = response)
    return render_template("form.html")

    #This is my html form: return render_template("form.html")
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: It did display my .html file however, if I try to query using the URL, it will still display the .html form instead of returning a .json file